# Ошибки: OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error, CGI script exit status 0x7f00

Tags: python, cgi

python3.3.4, все права 777

Сервер cgihttpd:

```
from http.server import CGIHTTPRequestHandler, test
test(CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
```

Форма friends.htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
    <title>Friends CGI Demo (static screen)</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Friends list for: <i>New User</i></h3>
    <form action="/cgi-bin/friendsA.py">
        <b>Enter your Name:</b>
        <input type="text" name="person" value="New User" size="15">
        <p><b>How many friends do you have?</b></p>
        <input type="radio" name="howmany" value="10"> 0
        <input type="radio" name="howmany" value="10"> 10
        <input type="radio" name="howmany" value="25" checked> 25
        <input type="radio" name="howmany" value="50"> 50
        <input type="radio" name="howmany" value="100"> 100
        <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

CGI скрипт:

```
import cgi

reshtml = '''Content-Type: text/html\n
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>
Friends CGI Demo (dynamic screen)
</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY><H3>Friends list for: <I>%s</I></H3>
Your name is: <B>%s</B>
You have <B>%s</B> friends.
</BODY></HTML>'''

form = cgi.FieldStorage
who = form['person'].value
howmany = form['howmany'].value
print(reshtml % (who, who, howmany))
```

Traceback:

```
/home/insiderz/virtenv334/bin/python /home/insiderz/PycharmProjects/CGI_WSGI/cgihttpd.py
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Apr/2017 16:44:15] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Apr/2017 16:44:18] "GET /cgi-bin/friendsA.py?person=New+User&howmany=25 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/http/server.py", line 1131, in run_cgi
    os.execve(scriptfile, args, env)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/home/insiderz/PycharmProjects/CGI_WSGI/cgi-bin/friendsA.py'
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Apr/2017 16:44:18] CGI script exit status 0x7f00
```

Comment: shebang добавьте. Связанный вопрос [OSError: [Errno 8\] Exec format error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27606653/4279)

Answer (score 2):

Верно, не хватало `#!/usr/bin/env python` вначале cgi скрипта.

А также скобок в строке 
`form = cgi.FieldStorage()`